# Write to stdin of a running process in windows

Tags: c#, python, process, cmd, stdin

I want to write data to an existing process's `stdin` from an external process in Windows.

I found similar questions for Linux, but I want to know how I can do the same in Windows.

> [How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process)
>
> [How do you stream data into the STDIN of a program from different local/remote processes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792054/how-do-you-stream-data-into-the-stdin-of-a-program-from-different-local-remote-pr)
>
> https://serverfault.com/questions/443297/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-using-pipe

I tried with this code but I got an error. I also tried running the program, sending `stdin` to that with this code, but again, it errored.

In CMD:

```
type my_input_string | app.exe -start
my_input_string | app.exe -start
app.exe -start < pas.txt
```

In python:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('"C:\app.exe" -start', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)  
grep_stdout = p.communicate(input='my_input_string')[0]
```

The error I get is:

> `ReadConsole()` failed: The handle is invalid.

And in C#:

```
try
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text;
    startInfo.Arguments = textBox2.Text;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    var streamWriter = process.StandardInput;
    streamWriter.WriteLine("1");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    textBox4.Text = ex.Message+"\r\n"+ex.Source;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of windows, front-most says "client.exe has stopped working".]

In C#, with the code above, `App.exe` (command line application which starts the other process) crashes, but in C# application I don't have any exception. I think that is because of `UseShellExecute = false`.

If I choose "don't run app in background" when I run the C# app, I can find the process and use `sendkeys` to send `my_input_string` to it, but this isn't a good idea because the user can see the commandline when it's running the GUI.

How can I send `stdin`, only using CMD, a python script, or C#, without any errors?

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry, but I can't figure out...who is writing to who? Python to C#? C# to Python? Do you want the general case?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I want a way to write to stdin from python or C# i try for write script in python and run that from C#.

Comment: Check out the `errorwindow.py` module in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091356/355230) of mine because it does what I think you're trying to do. The major difference is that output from one process is sent to the other by printing it (or writing it to `stderr`). The same module was also used to accomplish something similar in this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27932575/355230) of mine to a related question.

Answer (score 7):

If you're launching, and then supplying the input from c#, you can do something like this:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("path/to/executable");
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

var streamWriter = process.StandardInput;
streamWriter.WriteLine("I'm supplying input!");
```

If you need to write to the standard input of an application already running, I doubt that is easy to do with .net classes, as the Process class will not give you the `StandardInput` (it will instead throw an `InvalidOperationException`)

**Edit**:
Added parameter to `ProcessStartInfo()`

Comment: Thnx for your answer buy I try and when i use command line program crashed ! and also no any exception ! do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Run it in the debugger and give me the exception info, please.

Comment: Updated question, and add pic, and in C# i dont have any exception !

Comment: Oh dear, sorry. I left out a rather important step. See edit.

Comment: I see and add `startinfo.filename` and `startinfo.Arguments`  my exception i in other process after start stoped `Unhandled exception at 0x70FD6ECC (libxml2-2.dll) in client.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000001C.`

Answer (score -1):

This question has been around for a while, but I hope it helps with the answer.

I needed to do something similar, using the aircrack-ng application suite, this suite receives a string through STDIN, the solution I found is available at this link:
[C# output string to aircrack-ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808813/c-sharp-output-string-to-aircrack-ng)

Basically what you need is to start your python application, as a sub-process of the C# application.

Assuming that the python app is waiting for STDIN writing, it would look something like this:

```
public void WriteToAnotherProcess(string textToWrite)
{
    try
    {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process FirstProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text; // here the full path to the app that is waiting for the STDIN input
            startInfo.Arguments = textBox2.Text; //Arguments for second app
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            FirstProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            FirstProcess.Start();

            StreamWriter FirstProcessWriter = FirstProcess.StandardInput;
            StreamReader FirstProcessReader = FirstProcess.StandardOutput;

            FirstProcess.WriteLine(textToWrite);
            FirstProcess.Close();
            FirstProcess.WaitForExit();

            textBox4.Text = $"The return(STDOUT) from second app is: {FirstProcessReader.ReadToEnd()}";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBox4.Text = ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.Source;
    }
}
```

If your application is crashing during execution, as you mentioned, you can use the property:
**RedirectStandardError** available in **ProcessStartInfo**.

Getting the error return directly from the python application, so you will be able to understand what is really happening