# Python / Tkinter : How to access a ScrolledText widget from within a method?

Tags: python, user-interface, oop, methods, tkinter

I'd like to create a simple, reusable text output window class in Python / Tkinter that functions just like the console output, but with a nicer window.

So far I managed to write text into a `ScrolledText` widget directly from within the constructor,  but that is not what I want.

I'd like to create a `print` or `println` method that lets me add text from the main procedure any time.

How can I 'call' the text widget from within the print method?

**My *main* procedure:**

```
    from gui.simpleio import Textwindow 

    a = Textwindow("This is my Textwindow !")
    a.print("I'd like to see a hello from the print method")
    a.stxt.INSERT("but nothing happens")
```

**My *Textwindow* class in the *gui* package (*simpleio.py*):**

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, INSERT
    from tkinter import scrolledtext

    class Textwindow(Frame):

        def __init__(self , title):
            root = Tk()  
            stxt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root)
            stxt.pack()
            root.wm_title(title)
            stxt.insert(INSERT,"blah\nblabla\n")
            stxt.insert(INSERT,"yes\nno")
            root.mainloop()

        def print(self,text):
            #self.stxt.insert(INSERT,text)       
            pass
```

Comment: Please don't use bold for everything, just for the important things.

Comment: `Textwindow.print()` doesn't work because `self.stxt` isn't defined in `Textwindow.__init__()`.

Comment: Also, the `__init__` method of `TextWindow` calls `root.mainloop()` so the following `a.print` call won't be executed until the main window is destroyed.

Comment: Take a look at the `errorwindow.py` module in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091356/355230) to the question [_Writing to easygui textbox as function is running_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089506/writing-to-easygui-textbox-as-function-is-running-python).

Answer (score 0):

Give your TextWindow a write method and instance `a` becomes a file open for writing.  Here is simplified version of Lib/idlelib/OutputWindow's  OutputWindow.write.

```
# Act as output file
def write(self, s):
    self.text.insert('insert', s)
    self.text.see('insert')
    self.text.update()
    return len(s)
```

After adding this, `print('Hello in TextWindow', file=a)` should work in 3.x or 2.7 with print_function future import.